# How to path-clip an arc of n angle from a square?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The blue and red lines are the height limit.
The function should respect the lines
with any angle so nothing important is lost from the square.
The arc is to ilustrate a position in a circular selection interface.
The function is not closing.

More details are not possible to get at the moment

Picture of fail
[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Part of the code

```js
var rotatePoint = function(center, point, angle) {
    var cos = Math.cos(angle);
    var sin = Math.sin(angle);
    var rotatedx = (cos * (point.x - center.x)) + (sin * (point.y - center.y)) + center.x;
    var rotatedy = (cos * (point.y - center.y)) - (sin * (point.x - center.x)) + center.y;
    return { x: rotatedx, y: rotatedy };
};

var cutArc = function(size, angle) {
    angle = (Math.PI / 180) * angle;

    var vid = document.createElement("div");
    vid.style.position = "fixed";
    vid.style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
    vid.style.backgroundSize = "contain";
    vid.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    vid.style.color = "#FFF";
    vid.style.left = 
    (window.innerWidth/2 - size/2)+"px";
    vid.style.top = 
    (window.innerHeight/2 - size/2)+"px";
    vid.style.width = size+"px";
    vid.style.height = size+"px";
    vid.style.borderLeft = "2px solid orange";
    vid.style.borderRight = "2px solid orange";
    vid.style.zIndex = "99999";

    var lines = document.createElement("div");
    lines.style.position = "absolute";
    lines.style.left = "-2px";
    lines.style.top = (size/3)+"px";
    lines.style.width = (size)+"px";
    lines.style.height = (size/3)+"px";
    lines.style.border = "none";
    lines.style.outlineTop = "1px solid blue";
    lines.style.borderTop = "1px solid blue";
    lines.style.borderBottom = "1px solid red";
    lines.style.outlineBottom = "1px solid red";
    lines.style.zIndex = "99999";

    var distance = (Math.PI/angle)*size;
    console.log(distance);

    // Size
    var center = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    var i = { x: -size/2, y: 0 };

    var point = rotatePoint(center, i, angle);
    var pointA = rotatePoint(center, point, -(angle/2));
    var pointB = rotatePoint(center, point, (angle/2));
    console.log(pointA, pointB);

    var co = Math.abs(pointB.x - pointA.x);
    var ca = Math.abs(pointB.y - pointA.y);
    var h = Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow(co, 2)+
        Math.pow(ca, 2));
    console.log(h);

    var sc = (1/(size))*h;

    var startPointA = { x: 0, y: -(size/2) };
    var startPointB = { x: 0, y: -(size/2)+(size/3) };
    var polygon = [];
    var ra = (angle/20);
    var rb = (angle/10);

    for (var k = 10; k > -11; k --) {
        var rak = ra * k;
        var v = rotatePoint(center, startPointA, rak);
        polygon.push(v);
    }

    for (var k = -5; k < 6; k ++) {
        var rak = rb * k;
        var v = rotatePoint(center, startPointB, rak);
        polygon.push(v);
    }
    console.log(polygon);

    var path = "polygon(";
    for (var k in polygon) {
        var off = (100/sc) - 100;
        var px = ((((100/sc) / (size)) *
        (polygon[k].x + (size/2)))-(off/2));
        var py = ((((100/sc) / (size)) *
        (polygon[k].y + (size/3) + (size/2)))-(off/2));
        path += px+"% "+py+"%";
        path += k < (polygon.length-1) ?
        "," : "";
    }
    path += ")";
    console.log(path);

    vid.style.clipPath = path;
    //vid.style.background = "gold";
    vid.appendChild(lines);
    document.body.appendChild(vid);
};
cutArc(300, 360/3);
```

Comment: I am very unclear what your question is. Are you trying to make the second circle, the one with photo fragments in it? What is the first image of? Perhaps if you created a runnable snippet of the code you have so far it would be clearer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Added the snippet!

Comment: Could you say what you are trying to achieve. Is it the second circle with the photos? And please make a runnable snippet.

Comment: The arc need to stay between the blue and red lines to fit in the circle.